# Hat not texturing properly

Tags: texturing

I have created this top hat, which has 3 main parts: the base, the band and the top.
Originally, I created the hat incorrectly, I used materials instead of textures. I now want to use this as a textured Roblox hat for a game, but I can’t paint it to look like the original because when painting the band, it also paints the rest of the hat, like in the video below. How would I get the hat to look like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- In *Edit* mode, select the part you want to paint:

[image]

- Switch to *Texture Paint* mode, enable the *Paint Mask* option:

[image]

- Paint:

[image]

It should work:

[image]

If it paints on unexpected parts it may be because the margin between the UV islands is not large enough, in that case go into the *UV Editor* then *UV > Pack Islands* and in the *Operator* box on the bottom left increase the *Margin*:

[image]

Comment: will this allow me to export the entire texture of the hat to one image?

Comment: yes, if you use only one Image Texture in your material

Comment: i can mostly color just the band now, but certain parts outside of the mask still get painted when painting the mask (band)

Comment: yes, because as I said, you probably need to increase the margin between the UV islands, also maybe the brush bleeding option is too high but I doubt it's the case by default

Comment: so even putting the margin all the way up to 1.00 would fix this?